# $ is not defined lightgallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, lightgallery

For some reason my lightgallery is not working. I added it the same way I always do and all javascript files are included after Jquery.

I get this message in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at product-1.html:433
(anonymous) @ product-1.html:433
```

Which points to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#lightgallery").lightGallery();
    });
</script>
```

All files are correctly loaded, I checked in the network tab.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it? Maybe there is a conflict somewhere? Can I wrap it in a function to make it work?

My js files:

[image]

Comment: Look in the console network tab to see if jQuery is loading and only loading one version

Comment: is there more code in product-1.html? its complaining about something at line 433

Comment: @mplungjan Yes it's only loaded once.

Comment: Try to replace your js/jQuery.js with https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: @hairmot No it's pointing to the lightgallery code. The part I highlighted at the bottom of the image.

Comment: @VforVendetta I still have the same error even with the CDN loaded.

Comment: remove $ from $(document).ready(function()), and check

Comment: @VforVendetta Then the error is: `document.ready is not a function`

Comment: Try commenting all js files except jquery and comment google map related code for a while and check

Comment: @VforVendetta Thanks, it works when I remove bootstrap.js Weird, never would've thought that would cause a conflict.

Comment: You are welcome !!. And replace your google map script with https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAa5j5PXOoThi9oSiADE6wzQLNbstY3Q-g and then check. There is no api key included in your script, but iff map not working

Comment: Check of the bootstrap version matches the jQuery. They should work fine together

Answer (score 4):

in the head

```
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lightgallery.js/master/dist/css/lightgallery.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

your html content

```
<div id="lightgallery">
  <a href="img/img1.jpg">
      <img src="img/thumb1.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="img/img2.jpg">
      <img src="img/thumb2.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

in the body include light gallery js files after jquery

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lightgallery.js/master/dist/js/lightgallery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-pager.js/master/dist/lg-pager.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-autoplay.js/master/dist/lg-autoplay.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-fullscreen.js/master/dist/lg-fullscreen.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-zoom.js/master/dist/lg-zoom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-hash.js/master/dist/lg-hash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-share.js/master/dist/lg-share.js"></script>
<script>
   lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'));
</script>
```

This really works for me.

Comment: This works!
You might want to add `<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-thumbnail.js/master/dist/lg-thumbnail.js"></script>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing browser cache may help sometimes. Or narrow down your problem by loading one by one starting with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem :

```
<script>
   lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'));
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

1.Check your maps api js link like https://developers.google.com/maps/api/js this is correct or not
2.Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> button at a same time and clear caches and cookies